Understanding locks in java
I am trying to understand locks in java, and I am having trouble grasping the concept.
Here is a sample java code with locks:
public class LockQ {

    class Shared {
       static int count = 0;
    }

    class LockExample implements Runnable {
       Lock lock;

       public LockExample(Lock lock) {
          this.lock = lock;
       }

       @Override
       public void run() {
           lock.lock();

           for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                System.out.println("Working on count = " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                Shared.count++;
            }

            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LockQ obj = new LockQ();
        obj.demo();
    }

    public void demo() {
        Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();

        LockExample l1 = new LockExample(lock);
        LockExample l2 = new LockExample(lock);
        LockExample l3 = new LockExample(lock);

        Thread t1 = new Thread(l1);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(l2);
        Thread t3 = new Thread(l3);

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();

        /*
        try {
            t2.join();
            t3.join();
            t1.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
             throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        */

        System.out.println("Final count value " + Shared.count);
    }
}

Here is a sample output
Working on count = Thread-0 
Working on count = Thread-0 
Working on count = Thread-0 
Working on count = Thread-0 
Working on count = Thread-0 
Working on count = Thread-1 
Working on count = Thread-1
Working on count = Thread-1 
Working on count = Thread-1 
Working on count = Thread-1 
Working on count = Thread-2 
Working on count = Thread-2 
Working on count = Thread-2 
Working on count = Thread-2
Working on count = Thread-2 
Final count value 0

My confusion is:
Why is the count value at the end equal 0?
It do gets printed after all the print statements inside the loop has completed, which means that all the three threads have finished execution.
The code works as expected if the join statements are uncommented, and at the end I get:

Final count value as 15


If you comment out join() methods, main thread doesn't wait for the threads(t1, t2, t3) to complete. Try to put a sleep of 1 sec in your run method and switch between comment/uncomment join to see the output of printlin in for-loop and help yourself understand this better.

If you don't .join() the threads, they are not guaranteed to complete before later work takes place (.join() waits for the thread to exit before continuing)!
So what happens is your main program runs, then hangs while it waits for the threads to exit, but because it happens very quickly, you may not see the effect

"Hang" would mean that the program never terminates. If it terminates, then it did not hang.

@SolomonSlow the main thread hangs due to the halting problem, though it's fairly clear in this case that it should result in a clean exit!

I don't understand. How does OP's code have any connection to the halting problem? Why do you say, "the main thread hangs" in one sentence, and then say "it should result in a clean exit" in the next?

since the output shows "Working on count = Thread-0" 5 times before the final output, we must assume that it got incremented at least 4 times - actually adding a System.out.println("end") after the unlock, we will see that message for every Thread before seeing the final message, indicating the Thread exited the loop. and still get the last message with count value 0


Why is the count value at the end equal 0? [even though] all the three threads have finished execution?

This actually is a quite complicated subject. The details can be found in chapter 17 of the Java Language Specification (JLS), but you might learn the basics more quickly if you find a good tutorial.
The TLDR version is that your main thread is not synchronized with the other threads when it accesses Shared.count. The Java system is under no obligation to let your main thread see what the other threads did to that variable when it is not synchronized.
t.join() is one form of synchronization. I don't know why your other three threads were able to print out all fifteen messages before the main thread printed its message, but without the join calls, even then, there is no guarantee that the main thread will be able to see what they did.

lock.lock() is another form of synchronization. Your three worker threads all will be guaranteed to see what each other did because they only access the shared variable while keeping the lock locked.

"I don't know why your other three threads were able to print out all fifteen messages before the main thread printed its message" -- I am wondering that too, with Java 8 the message is often printed before the second Thread starts printing, sometimes even before the first one does (which I was kind of expecting / used to)- scheduling must have been changed, since with Java 24 (and 21) I can reproduce the question's output
